Correct way to implement DI with Clean Architecture & Koin
Following example: I have an Android with separated in several modules:
Core: database data, domain 
Feature: student
In this case, data dependes on database, domain dependes on data and student dependes on domain: 
database > data > domain > student
In each module I have a File which provides the layer-specific classes with Koin modules:
val <module>Module = {
    ...
}

To assemble everything together, I add ALL modules to my app module to provide the when I start koin:
startKoin {
    DatabaseModule,
    DataModule,
    DomainModule,
    StudenModule
}

This approach works, but I wonder if this is the correct way or not, since it feels I'm breaking the separation of concerns rule.
